# All zeroes of monic cubic $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ are negative reals and $a\lt3$. Range of $b+c$?

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

$a,b,c$ are real numbers. I have to find the range of values of $b+c$.

So, I started off by assuming $\alpha , \beta , \gamma$ as the roots.
This gives us $\alpha \beta \gamma = -c$ and $\sum{\alpha\beta}=b$.

From the above two equations, we can conclude that both $b$ and $c$ are positive.

Also, $\alpha + \beta + \gamma \gt -3$ since the sum of roots is equal to $-a$. Now, if we consider $\alpha' , \beta' , \gamma'$ as the positive counterparts of our three roots, we can use the AM GM inequality.
We get:
$\frac{\alpha'+\beta'+\gamma'}3\ge(\alpha' \beta'\gamma')^{1/3}$
Replacing values in above equation, we get $\frac a3 \ge c^{1/3}$.

Since $a<3$, we get $c<1$.

That's where I'm stuck. I have no idea how to get the range of values for $b$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative $3x^2+2ax+b$ has also two real, negative roots. Then 
$$4a^2-12b\ge0$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why is this answer being accepted? It doesn't answer the question in any way, it just bounds $b$. It is helpful, sure, but in my opinion should not be acctepted

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure though, the derivative must have two distinct roots because unless the graph of the function turns twice (local minima/maxima), it can't cross the x-axis thrice, and hence can't have three roots, right?

Comment: A bound of $b$ is exactly what OP was asking for. And answering his question, the polynomial could have a triple root. Only in this case the roots of the derivative are equal.

Comment: Excuse me, I have misread the question. My mistake, forget that I commented anything.

Comment: @vrugtehagel read my comment just now. Plus, this gives me b <3 and since c <1, we get b+c <4. The answer in answer key is 0< b+c <4. So, to me this seems correct

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(\alpha-1)(\beta-1)(\gamma-1)=-1-a-b-c$.

So, we need to find the range of $(\alpha-1)(\beta-1)(\gamma-1)$.

Let $\alpha', \beta',\gamma'$ be absolute values of the roots.

Hence, $|(\alpha-1)(\beta-1)(\gamma-1)|=(\alpha'+1)(\beta'+1)(\gamma'+1)$.

So, let's find the bounds of the $(\alpha'+1)(\beta'+1)(\gamma'+1)$.

Since roots are negative, we have $\alpha'>0, \beta'>0,\gamma'>0$, or

$(\alpha'+1)(\beta'+1)(\gamma'+1)>1$. That's lower bound.

Since a<3, we have $\alpha'+ \beta'+\gamma'<3$, so

$(\alpha'+1)(\beta'+1)(\gamma'+1)\leq(\frac{\alpha'+1+\beta'+1+\gamma'+1}{3})^3<8$.

Hence, we have that bounds are $-1$ and $-8$, so:

$$-1>(\alpha-1)(\beta-1)(\gamma-1)>-8$$
$$-1>-1-a-b-c>-8$$
$$-a<b+c<7-a$$
and since $b+c>0$, $a>0$ always, we have $$0<b+c<7-a$$

Comment: Okay, first of all, I don't fully get how you got where you did. But, in your answer b+c is always greater than 3. The answer key says 0<b+c<4. The upper limit is correct, but there is something wrong with the lower limit (or the answer is wrong). Anyway, sorry to say, but I find this answer to be a bit too complicated for me

Comment: @PratyushYadav I edited the lower bound, and this proof is ok! That's your choice to choose a proof which is more convinient for you, so it is fine!

Comment: Yep, it looks correct now.